# How to translate this working code the python way

Tags: python, dictionary

For standard response purposes, I need to convert a string from this:

```
[(('Ethyl', 'alcohol'), 1.0), (('clean', 'water'), 1.0)]
```

to this:

```
[{"words": "Ethyl,alcohol", "score": 1.0}, {"words": "clean,water", "score": 1.0}]
```

I was able to code it correctly but my code doesn't seems like "pythony".. Here is my code:

```
lst = []
for data in dataList:
    dct = {}
    dct['words'] = data[0][0] + ',' + data[0][1]
    dct['score'] = data[1]
    lst.append(dct)

sResult = json.dumps(lst)
print(sResult)
```

Is my code acceptable? I will be dealing with this more often and would like to see a more readable way the python way.

Comment: This question is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) *[meta: what was the short code again?]*

Comment: You can use `dct['words'] = ','.join(data[0])`

Comment: @mkrieger1 [Help-page for commenting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), seems to be `codereview.se` in brackets: [codereview.se]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this using comprehension:

```
dataList = [(('Ethyl', 'alcohol'), 1.0), (('clean', 'water'), 1.0)]

[{'words': ','.join(x), 'score': y} for x, y in dataList]
```

output:

```
[{'words': 'Ethyl,alcohol', 'score': 1.0},
 {'words': 'clean,water', 'score': 1.0}]
```

Comment: i played with it and I need to dump as json for my desired result :
json.dumps([{'word': ','.join(x), 'score': y} for x, y in dataList])

Answer (score 1):

The 2 ways that you can use to shorten your code, not more readable for sure, but this can be prefered, are

- inline a dict construction

  ```
  lst = []
  for data in dataList:
      lst.append({'words': data[0][0] + ',' + data[0][1], 'score' : data[1]})
  ```
- Use a list comprehension

  ```
   lst = [{'words': data[0][0] + ',' + data[0][1], 'score': data[1]} for data in dataList]
  ```